# Interactive logistic map

Tags: java, performance, beginner

The purpose of this project is to generate an interactive [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map). The user can click on the produced picture to magnify the picture at that point.

Here is the logistic map equation:

[image]

Here is my program:

```
public class LogisticMap {
    public static double returnLogisticEquation(double x, double r) {
        return r * x * (1 - x);
    }

    public static double ignoreFirstIterations(int numberOfIterations, double x, double r) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++) {
            x = returnLogisticEquation(x, r);
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static void drawLogisticMap(int numberOfHorizontalPoints, int numberOfVerticalPoints, double leftOfRInterval, double rightOfRInterval, double x) {
        StdDraw.setYscale(0, 1);
        StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();
        double subintervalLength = (rightOfRInterval - leftOfRInterval) / numberOfHorizontalPoints;
        int numberOfIterations = 1000;
        for (double r = leftOfRInterval; r < rightOfRInterval; r += subintervalLength) {
            x = ignoreFirstIterations(numberOfIterations, x, r);
            for (int p = 0; p < numberOfVerticalPoints; p++) {
                x = returnLogisticEquation(x, r);
                StdDraw.point(r, x);
            }
        }
        StdDraw.show();
    }
    
    public static void interactiveLogisticMap(int numberOfHorizontalPoints, int numberOfVerticalPoints, double leftOfRInterval, double rightOfRInterval, double x) {
        StdDraw.setXscale(leftOfRInterval, rightOfRInterval);
        drawLogisticMap(numberOfHorizontalPoints, numberOfVerticalPoints, leftOfRInterval, rightOfRInterval, x);

        double r = 0;
        double y = 0;
        double scale = 0.05;

        while (true) {
            if (StdDraw.isMousePressed()) {
                r = StdDraw.mouseX();
                y = StdDraw.mouseY();

                double newLeftOfRInterval = r - scale;
                double newRightOfRInterval = r + scale;
                double belowRInterval = y - scale;
                double aboveRInterval = y + scale;

                StdDraw.setXscale(newLeftOfRInterval, newRightOfRInterval);
                StdDraw.setYscale(belowRInterval, aboveRInterval);
                StdDraw.clear();
                drawLogisticMap(numberOfHorizontalPoints, numberOfVerticalPoints, newLeftOfRInterval, newRightOfRInterval, x);

                scale /= 10;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StdDraw.setCanvasSize(850, 850);

        int numberOfHorizontalPoints = 800;
        int numberOfVerticalPoints = 1000;
        double leftOfRInterval = 2.4;
        double rightOfRInterval = 4;
        double x = Math.random();

        interactiveLogisticMap(numberOfHorizontalPoints, numberOfVerticalPoints, leftOfRInterval, rightOfRInterval, x);
    }
}
```

[StdDraw](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html) is a simple API written by the authors of the book *Computer Science An Interdisciplinary Approach*. I checked my program and it works. Here is one instance of it.

Output (actually a succession of outputs):

[image]

[image]

Is there any way that I can improve my program?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
public static double returnLogisticEquation(double x, double r) {
```

The name is not quite correct, as it does return the result of equation, not the equation itself, so more like `calculateLogisticEquation`.

---

```java
    public static double returnLogisticEquation(double x, double r) {
        return r * x * (1 - x);
    }
```

I'm torn on this one. Normally, I say that you are only allowed to use single-letter variables when dealing with dimensions (yes, that disallows "i", "j", "k" too). However, when implementing mathematical functions there *might* be a reason to use them. However, using the long names might still be an improvement:

```java
    public static double returnLogisticEquation(double populationRatio, double reproductionate) {
        return reproductionRate * populationRatio * (1 - populationRatio);
    }
```

---

```java
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++) {
```

That's what I meant:

```java
for (int counter = 0; counter < numberOfIterations; counter++) {
```

---

```java
public static double ignoreFirstIterations(int numberOfIterations, double x, double r) {
```

I'm not sure about the name here, maybe `forward(int numberOfIterations, ...)` would be a better name, as normally, I'd not assume a function that ignores something to return something.

---

```java
    public static double ignoreFirstIterations(int numberOfIterations, double x, double r) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++) {
            x = returnLogisticEquation(x, r);
        }
        return x;
    }
```

Assigning to a parameter is bad style. Even though you *can* treat it as just another declaration, it might lead to confusion down the line. For example if you have an object as parameter and the following line:

```java
thisIsAParameter.setValue("value");
```

If you have the habit of assigning parameters, you now need to check whether there was a different object assigned to the parameter before that function call. Ideally, parameters would be `final`, but that is quite noisy, though. Threat them as `final`.

---

```java
int numberOfIterations = 1000;
```

It's not the number of iterations, it's the number of *ignored* iterations.

---

```java
r += subintervalLength
```

For the record: `+=` and other shorthand operators are not short for `a = a + b`, but for `a = (TYPE_A)(a+b)`, which might yield unexpected results. For example, `intA = intA + 5.5d` will yield an error that a `double` is truncated to an `int`. `intA += 5.5d` will yield no such error.

---

```java
    public static void drawLogisticMap(int numberOfHorizontalPoints, int numberOfVerticalPoints, double leftOfRInterval, double rightOfRInterval, double x) {
        StdDraw.setYscale(0, 1);
        StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();
        double subintervalLength = (rightOfRInterval - leftOfRInterval) / numberOfHorizontalPoints;
        int numberOfIterations = 1000;
        for (double r = leftOfRInterval; r < rightOfRInterval; r += subintervalLength) {
            x = ignoreFirstIterations(numberOfIterations, x, r);
            for (int p = 0; p < numberOfVerticalPoints; p++) {
                x = returnLogisticEquation(x, r);
                StdDraw.point(r, x);
            }
        }
        StdDraw.show();
    }
```

A few more empty lines to group logic would be nice (like you've done in other functions).

```java
    public static void drawLogisticMap(int numberOfHorizontalPoints, int numberOfVerticalPoints, double leftOfRInterval, double rightOfRInterval, double x) {
        StdDraw.setYscale(0, 1);
        StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();
        
        double subintervalLength = (rightOfRInterval - leftOfRInterval) / numberOfHorizontalPoints;
        int numberOfIterations = 1000;
        
        for (double r = leftOfRInterval; r < rightOfRInterval; r += subintervalLength) {
            x = ignoreFirstIterations(numberOfIterations, x, r);
            
            for (int p = 0; p < numberOfVerticalPoints; p++) {
                x = returnLogisticEquation(x, r);
                
                StdDraw.point(r, x);
            }
        }
        
        StdDraw.show();
    }
```

---

```java
while (true) {
```

If you can include a dynamic break condition, do so (like listening for ESC).

---

```java
        double r = 0;
        double y = 0;
```

Declare variables where they are used, to limit the scope in which they exist to limit possible errors.

```java
                double r = StdDraw.mouseX();
                double y = StdDraw.mouseY();
```

---

```java
double scale = 0.05;
```

Seems more like this should either be a parameter, or a class-level constant.

---

I haven't tested your code or verified the mathematical correctness, but looks good so far.